# Join table on conditions, count on conditions

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *, null AS score,
       '0' AS SortOrder
    FROM products
    WHERE datelive = -1
    AND hidden = 0
UNION
SELECT e.*, (SUM(r.a)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.b)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.c)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.d)/(COUNT(*)*1.0))/4 AS score,
       '1' AS SortOrder
    FROM products e
    LEFT JOIN reviews r
        ON r.productID = e.productID
        WHERE e.hidden = 0
        AND e.datelive != -1
    GROUP BY e.productID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
UNION
SELECT e.*, (SUM(r.a)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.b)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.c)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.d)/(COUNT(*)*1.0))/4 AS score,
       '2' AS SortOrder
    FROM products e
    LEFT JOIN reviews r
        ON r.productID = e.productID
        WHERE e.hidden = 0
        AND e.datelive != -1
    GROUP BY e.productID
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
    ORDER BY SortOrder ASC, score DESC
```

This creates an SQL object for displaying products on a page. The first request grabs items of type `datelive = -1`, the second of type `datelive != -1` but `r.count(*) >= 5`, and the third of type `datelive != -1` and `r.count(*) < 5`. The reviews table is structured similar to the below:

```
 reviewID | productID | a | b | c | d | approved
-------------------------------------------------
    1           1       5   4   5   5      1
    2           5       3   2   5   5      0
    3           2       5   5   4   3      1
   ...         ...     ... ... ... ...    ...
```

I'm trying to work it such that `r.count(*)` only cares for rows of type `approved = 1`, since tallying data based on unapproved reviews isn't ideal. How can I join these tables such that the summations of scores and the number of rows is dependent only on `approved = 1`?

I've tried adding in `AND r.approved = 1` in the `WHERE` conditional for the joins and it doesn't do what I'd like. It does sort it properly, but then it no longer includes items with zero reviews.

Comment: What does happen if you add `AND r.approved = 1` to the `WHERE` of the third query? Also the WHERE isn't affecting your join criteria it's happening after the join criteria (although the RDBMS may make a smarter join depending on it) and filters rows out of the joined record set.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, adding `AND r.approved = 1` to the `WHERE` in the third query excludes all products with zero rows in the reviews table. If a product has no reviews, it no longer displays, when I'd like it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be nearly there.

In your question you talked about adding the AND r.approved = 1 to the join criteria but by the sounds of it you are actually adding it to the `WHERE` clause.

If you instead properly add it to the join criteria like below then it should work fine:

```
SELECT *, null AS score,
       '0' AS SortOrder
    FROM products
    WHERE datelive = -1
    AND hidden = 0
UNION
SELECT e.*, (SUM(r.a)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.b)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.c)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.d)/(COUNT(*)*1.0))/4 AS score,
       '1' AS SortOrder
    FROM products e
    LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.productID = e.productID
    WHERE e.hidden = 0
    AND e.datelive != -1
    GROUP BY e.productID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
UNION
SELECT e.*, (SUM(r.a)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.b)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.c)/(COUNT(*)*1.0)+
       SUM(r.d)/(COUNT(*)*1.0))/4 AS score,
       '2' AS SortOrder
    FROM products e
    LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.productID = e.productID AND r.approved = 1
    WHERE e.hidden = 0
    AND e.datelive != -1
    GROUP BY e.productID
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
    ORDER BY SortOrder ASC, score DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67fcd/1).

Notice again how I have simply put the `AND r.approved = 1` directly after `LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.productID = e.productID` which adds an extra criteria to the join.

As I mentioned in my comment, the WHERE clause will filter rows out of the combined record set after the join has been made. In some cases the RDBMS may optimise it out and put it into the join criteria but only where that would make no difference to the result set.

Comment: Cheers, this worked wonderfully. What a simple thing to miss; I wasn't sure why it would no longer show items of a null score, but this way ensures it still does. Simple and quick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the non-zero sums and joining it to your result may solve it;

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7702/17)

```
SELECT a.productID,
       NULL AS score,
       '0' AS SortOrder
FROM products a
WHERE datelive = -1
  AND hidden = 0
UNION
SELECT e.productID,
       (min(x.a)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0)+ min(x.b)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0)+ min(x.c)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0)+ min(x.d)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0))/4 AS score,
       '1' AS SortOrder
FROM products e
JOIN reviews r ON r.productID = e.productID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT ee.productID,
          sum(rr.a) AS a,
          sum(rr.b) AS b,
          sum(rr.c) AS c,
          sum(rr.d) AS d,
          count(*) AS cnt
   FROM products ee
   LEFT JOIN reviews rr ON ee.productID = rr.productID
   GROUP BY ee.productID) x ON e.productID = x.productID
WHERE e.hidden = 0
  AND e.datelive != -1
GROUP BY e.productID HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
UNION
SELECT e.productID,
       (min(x.a)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0)+ min(x.b)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0)+ min(x.c)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0)+ min(x.d)/(min(x.cnt)*1.0))/4 AS score,
       '2' AS SortOrder
FROM products e
LEFT JOIN reviews r ON r.productID = e.productID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT ee.productID,
          sum(rr.a) AS a,
          sum(rr.b) AS b,
          sum(rr.c) AS c,
          sum(rr.d) AS d,
          count(*) AS cnt
   FROM products ee
   LEFT JOIN reviews rr ON ee.productID = rr.productID
   GROUP BY ee.productID) x ON e.productID = x.productID
WHERE e.hidden = 0
  AND e.datelive != -1
GROUP BY e.productID HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
ORDER BY SortOrder ASC,
         score DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a temp table that only contains rows where approved = 1, and then join on the temp table instead of `reviews`.

```
create table tt_reviews like reviews;
insert into tt_reviews
select * from reviews
where approved = 1;
alter table tt_reviews add index(productID);
```

Then replace `reviews` with `tt_reviews` in your above query.